# Auto refresh in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In webforms I'd do

```
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
        setTimeout("location.reload(true);", timeoutPeriod);
    }
    </script>

    <body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(5000);">
```

or codebehind Page_Load

```
Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "5");
```

**Question**  How to make the screen refresh every 5 seconds in ASP.NET MVC3

Comment: Both of those approaches work exactly the same in MVC as they do in WebForms... :)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You could do the same in MVC:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload(true);
    }, timeoutPeriod);
}
</script>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(5000);">
    ...
</body>
```

or using a meta tag:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
```

or in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "5");
    return View();
}
```

Comment: What if I want to refresh my view only once?

Comment: @ISeeSharp You have to implement your own code using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

At least in .NET6.0 to add a header in the controller you should use:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    Response.Headers.Add("Refresh", "5");
    return View();
}
```