# "UpdatePanel" in Razor (mvc 3)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there something like UpdatePanel (in ASPX) for Razor?

I want to refresh data (e.g. table, chart, ...) automaticly every 30 seconds.
Similar to clicking the following link every 30 seconds:

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Refresh", "RefreshItems", new AjaxOptions() {
     UpdateTargetId = "ItemList",
     HttpMethod = "Post"})
```

Edit:

I may should add that the action link renders a partial view.

Code in cshtml:

```
<div id="ItemList">
  @Html.Partial("_ItemList", Model)
</div>
```

Code in Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RefreshItems() {
        try {
            // Fill List/Model
            ... 

            // Return Partial
            return PartialView("_ItemList", model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

It would be create if the PartielView could refresh itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try something similar to the following using Jquery (have not tested though)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function()
        {
         // not sure what the controller name is
          $.post('<%= Url.Action("Refresh", "RefreshItems") %>', function(data) {
           // Update the ItemList html element
           $('#ItemList').html(data);
          });
        }
        , 30000);
   });
</script>
```

The above code should be placed in the containing page i.e. not the partial view page. Bear in mind that the a partial view is not a complete html page.

My initial guess is that this script can be placed in the partial and modified as follows. Make sure that the ajax data type is set to `html`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function()
    {
      // not sure what the controller name is
      $.post('<%= Url.Action("Refresh", "RefreshItems") %>', function(data) {
        // Update the ItemList html element
        $('#ItemList').html(data);
      });
    }
    , 30000);
</script>
```

Another alternative is to store the javascript in a separate `js` file and use the [Jquery getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function in ajax success callback.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you don't need the AJAX expierience than use the HTML tag:

```
<meta http-equiv=”refresh” content=”30; URL=http://www.programmingfacts.com”>
```

go here: http://www.programmingfacts.com/auto-refresh-page-after-few-seconds-using-javascript/

Comment: Why should I use an UpdatePanel, if I don't need the Ajax experience?

Answer (score 3):

If someone wants the complete code for a selfupdating partial view have a look!

Code of the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RefreshSelfUpdatingPartial() {

            // Setting the Models Content
            // ...

            return PartialView("_SelfUpdatingPartial", model);
}
```

Code of the Partial (_SelfUpdatingPartial.cshtml):

```
@model YourModelClass

<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function () {
    $.post('@Url.Action("RefreshSelfUpdatingPartial")', function (data) {
            $('#SelfUpdatingPartialDiv').html(data);
        }
    );
}, 20000);
</script>
// Div
<div id="SelfUpdatingPartialDiv">

// Link to Refresh per Click
<p>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Aktualisieren", "RefreshFlatschels", new AjaxOptions() {
UpdateTargetId = "FlatschelList",
HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
})
</p>

// Your Code
// ...

</div>
```

Code to integrate the Partial in the "Main"-View (ViewWithSelfupdatingPartial.cs):

```
 @Html.Partial("_FlatschelOverview", Model)
```

Comment: What is `_FlatschelOverview` ? and `Aktualisieren` - `RefreshFlatschels` ? `FlatschelList` ?

Comment: Using `$('#SelfUpdatingPartialDiv').html(data);` you lost code *Link to Refresh per Click*: `@Ajax.ActionLink("Aktualisieren", "RefreshFlatschels"`

Answer (score 2):

The `<meta refresh ..>` tag in HTML will work for you. Its the best option

Answer (score 0):

Traditional controls don't works in ASP MVC

You could do it using Jquery timers http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers

Other option could be to use the [Delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function

In your target is as simple as refresh the whole page, this SO link will be of your interest: [Auto refresh in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396282/auto-refresh-in-asp-net-mvc)

Hope It Helps.

Comment: Of Course. You can this techniques in partial views.