# Update View with new data MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, timer

I'm working on a project where I have to keep data that is up to date. I've been working on using a Timer to keep the data that my controller has synced with my DB every x seconds.
My problem is that I can't get my View to Update/Refresh/Reload when the data is updated.
I don't have to get the page to update without clicking anything on the page.

**Index method**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (aTimer.Enabled == false)
        {
            initTimer();
        }
        var ordersLinks = db.OrdersLinks.Include(o => o.List).Include(s => s.Order_Stop_Link).Include(i => i.OrdersInfoes);
        return View(ordersLinks.ToList());
    }
```

**Timer Event** *Timer is a System.Timers.Timer*

```
public void TimerEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var OldDB = db.OrdersLinks.FirstOrDefault().OrderNr;

        foreach (var entity in db.ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            entity.Reload();
        }
        var NewDB = db.OrdersLinks.FirstOrDefault().OrderNr;

        if (OldDB != NewDB)
        {
            Index(); //This calls into the Index Method but doesnt update the view
            //RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

**SOLVED**
I used SignalR thanks to the comments, special thanks to @Stephen Muecke.

Comment: Hi @Jemomi_DK , you can refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396282/auto-refresh-in-asp-net-mvc). Hope it helps. :-)

Comment: There is no point putting a timer in the server method. It would need to be in the view (using javascript timer to call a method using ajax which returns a partial view so you can update the DOM). But you should consider using SignalR to push changes to the client.

Comment: Your indexmethod returns a View. But you arent doing anyting with this result. Please provide some more code and let us see what your View-Method does.

Comment: @lokusking the return View will should pass back the data list to a View call "Index". So I don't see that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks alot for all the comments!
after more trial and error i have desided to try out SignalR since it sounds like it can do everything i need. special thanks to @Stephen Muecke.
I will update the post if/when i get something working.