# dynamically refresh web page according to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building a website using ASP.NET. I need to auto-refresh my webpage according to the database changes every minute. I have been reading about System.Timers but not sure how to implement it on MVC controller.
Here's my sample code.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //write the code to refresh page every 1 min

        var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
        MySQL msql = new MySQL();                          
        List<string> status = msql.SelectList("Select * from table");
        //query database
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way to drive this from the server. You need to drive it [in JavaScript in a timer on the client](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22154172/424129). It's more considerate to the user (and to your server) to do this with AJAX and merely update some HTML dynamically, rather than reloading the whole page.

Comment: This is a task for javascript.

Comment: [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396282/auto-refresh-in-asp-net-mvc) You will have to use javascript, but it is pretty simple.

Comment: @EdPlunkett You can do it from the server, you need to be able to call code on the client from the server. Technology like web sockets make that possible, with [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) being largely used for these sorts of things.

Comment: @mason Well, Today I Learned. Thank you. Still not the first thing I'd try though.

Comment: How about http://socket.io ? Does a lot of the heavy lifting for you with sockets.

Comment: Thank you guys!! I used JavaScript and it worked.