# Refresh the contents of a tabbed panel in Struts2

Tags: ajax, jsp, struts2

All,

I have a question regarding Tabbed Panel in Struts2.

If I have a few panels and I want the content on a tab to be updated every five seconds would how would I do this?

Also, I only want the tab which is currently being viewed to update at the given interval. The other tabs should update when selected and then continue t be updated every five seconds until the user selects another.

Can anyone suggest an approach which allow me to do these things?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a long running tradition in Stack Overflow where all Javascript problems can be solved with jQuery.

Here is a similar question with a div instead of a tab

[Auto-refreshing div with jQuery - setTimeout or another method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220767/auto-refreshing-div-with-jquery)