# jquery: reload multiple divs on page with ajax on interval X

Tags: jquery, ajax, reload

Im in the need to update several #divs on a page by using AJAX to call a function in my web app that returns a value. The value is a counter the idea is to update it in realtime this way.

```
function getTime(ID) returns = "12.00"
```

What would be a good way to implement this in query?

Im using below snippet to reload a section of a page but how to do this with multiple sections? any query guru's can help me on the right way? thx!

```
:javascript
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#basket").load('/gettime/<id value from id attribute to pass it???>');
      }, 10000);
      $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
```

Comment: did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193736/auto-refresh-multiple-divs-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one way you can do it is, use one class, say "**reload**" to all the divs that needs to be reloaded, set unique ids to those divs and do something like:

```
$('body').on('reloadTimeout', 'div.reload', function(event){
    //get the div id using 
    var divId = $(this).attr("id");
    //then do some ajax stuff like load to fetch content
});
window.setInterval(function(){ 
    body.trigger('reloadTimeout'); 
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Thx I tried but   $('body').on('reloadTimeout', 'div.timer', function(event){
 doesn't seem to be valid query?

Comment: Used the idea and it works reasonable well with a conversation to query