# Stop JQuery refreshing DIV

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I've been using the suggestion made in [Auto-refreshing div with jQuery - setTimeout or another method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220767/auto-refreshing-div-with-jquery) to refresh a div. The div is refreshing a php script that is calculating lots of numbers in the background.

Does anyone know how I can stop the DIV refreshing once a the calculation in the php script have finished loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple boolean or just an if statement.

```
finished = false;

function update()
{
   if ( finished )
      return;
   else
   {
      // continue calculating and call again
      window.setTimeout( update, 10000 );
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your timer is called `timer`, you can call the following to cancel the timer that refreshes the div.

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```