# How can I auto-update a news feed with javascript without refreshing the whole page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

How can I automatically update just the news feed of my site without updating the whole of it every 10 seconds?? I am creating a php code that pull information from an rss feed but I don't want the user to keep having to refresh the page.

I'm not sure what else to add, Thanks,
Cameron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jquery you may be interested in the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method, with a interval set correctly it could refresh your div/whatever every 10s ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the content of your website routinely without user refreshing the page, you could exploit [polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29) with AJAX.

For more details pls visit [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-dynamic-poll-with-jquery-and-php/).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a time interval while pulling the rss feeds.

See some related questions:

- [auto-refreshing div with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220767/auto-refreshing-div-with-jquery)
- [Parse RSS with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery)