# jQuery - Update a div on page without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make some Post Application which has to show messages like the Mail in Mac OSX.

I wan't to have headers shown in a div on the left of another div. The 'other div' has to show the message according to what header is selected.

All in all, I want the script to show some postContent matching postHeader, without refreshing the page - but still it has to add an URL statement like: `post.php?id=1`.

Is this even possible and how would you do that? :)

Comment: And how would you do that? :)

Comment: That's a different question. Have you attempted to do this yourself? I'm certainly not going to do it *for* you ;)

Comment: Sorry, I know ;) 
Well, I have tried to make it a link but then it's refreshing the page ofc.

Comment: Not to be snobby, but look at the bottom-right-hand corner of your screen. There are like 5 *identical* questions. You should find their code quite useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [auto-refreshing div with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220767/auto-refreshing-div-with-jquery)

Comment: Sorry, very much, I'll look at it. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a div with id `postContent` where you want the response to be inserted into and then use the following jQuery functionality:

```
    $('postContent').load('post.php?id=1');
```

API documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: If id has to be something different all the time, what would you do then? .load('post.php?id=1') has to change to id=2 if that's what clicked in the link?

Comment: my answer was just an example... 'post.php?id=2' is just a string; therefore, you can tweak it programmatically however you see fit. One example would be `$('postContent').load('post.php?id='+myId);` where you set the variable `myId` somewhere before calling load :)

Comment: ahh, okay then. I think I got it. Thanks Ryan. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Here's a good [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/) to get you started.