# Refresh only a div in php

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a chat box that i want to update :-) But I want only to refresh the div and not the hole page... Can someone help me??

Code:

```
<div align="right" id="chat">
<?php
include 'Chat.php';

?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't do it with a server side script like [php](/questions/tagged/php)

However, Using jQuery, when you need to update the div. Simply use

```
$("#chat").load("Chat.php");
```

For an example, make a request to the server when a user finishes typing on a textbox, and load the recent chat text.

```
$("#textbox").change(function() {
    $("#chat").load("Chat.php");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

checkout this one.
Its easy to implement and pretty useful.

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/auto-load-refresh-every-10-seconds-with.html

also see this

[Auto-refreshing div with jQuery - setTimeout or another method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220767/auto-refreshing-div-with-jquery)

Good luck..

Comment: What is wrong with this code


<html>
<head>


<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


 
</head>
<body>
<div id="page" align="center">

<?php
  include 'style.php'; 
 ?>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php?q=<?php echo $search_word; ?>').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>


<div id="load_tweets" align="rigth">
<?php
include 'messages.php';
?>

</div>

Answer (score 0):

If you are not that good at Javascript or Ajax or jQuery, then you might want to create a link with a get variable like include = 1, and when it is equal to one, include another page with the information you want. But it is worth learning jQuery and the like.