# Autopopulate View when user is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm willing to make the following ( C# MVC 3.0):
 -Update a View  when the user presses a button.
- Such button has an authentication form.
-If the user and pass he entered in the form is ok , the page where he is updates dynamically( so that the user remains has the impression that the page does not  in the same page).

It is something like this:

[Auto-refreshing div with jQuery - setTimeout or another method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220767/auto-refreshing-div-with-jquery)

Supposedly this should help but it does not

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820075/dynamically-creating-a-custom-user-control-then-rendering-it-in-a-mvc-razor-view

Comment: What errors have u got? I don't see question here.

Comment: Do you need to change the content of same view when user get authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to this?

```
@If Request.IsAuthenticated Then

    @<text>Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!
    [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>

Else

    @:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]

End If
```

Note:  This is VB.NET.