# Auto refresh <div> without reload entire page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to update the content of "mydiv" without refreshing the entire index page.
@mydata is given by mycontroller. I need to recalculate it every *n* seconds and pass it to "mydiv"

With "link_to" it works!

**index.html.erb**

```
<%=
    link_to('refresh', '/mycontroller/index', :remote => true)
%>

<div id="mydiv">
    <%=
        @mydata
    %>
</div>
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$('#mydiv').html('<%= escape_javascript(@mydata) %>')
```

Now I need to refresh the content of "mydiv" automatically every *n* seconds (so without click on the link). I have tried solutions from:

- [First Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220767/auto-refreshing-div-with-jquery)
- [Second Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052543/how-to-fire-ajax-request-periodically)

but no luck.

In my **application.js** I have writed this:

```
function executeQuery() {
  $.ajax({
    //url: '/index',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#mydiv').html(data)
    }
  });
  setTimeout(executeQuery, 500);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(executeQuery, 500);
});
```

---

**For who is facing my same problem, I solved it by replacing**

```
$('#mydiv').html(data)
```

with

```
$('#mydiv').load('/mycontroller/index #mydiv')
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `window.setTimeout(executeQuery, 500)`?

Comment: @SaurabhJain I think It's the same. It refresh but It returns all the page into "mydiv". I need to refresh only "mydata"

Comment: You need to create a page that has only the contents you want instead of loading the complete page.

Comment: @Juhana instead of using $('#mydiv').html(data), I have replaced it with $('#mydiv').load('/mycontroller/index #mydiv') and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval()` instead of using `setTimeout()`.

**Ref:** https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
function executeQuery() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'example.com/url/', // Provide your response URL here.
    success: function(data) {
      $('#mydiv').html(data);
    }
  });
}

setInterval(executeQuery(), (n * 1000)); // Replace 'n' with how many seconds you want.
```

This code will run the `executeQuery()` method in every 'n' seconds interval. So that your requirement is accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

Set layout to false in the action and just pass on the relevent content, not the entire page

```
def action1
   <your code here>
end
def action2
   <your code here>
   render :layout => false
end
```

Your view for action2 should have content pertaining only to #mydiv.

A better solution would be to use a single action and change render options based on type of request. (Ajax or non ajax)

Comment: This was solved 2 years ago. Answer is in my question.